# Bootstrap и Media запросы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Всем привет, при верстке, использую bootstrap.

Всегда приходится корректировать некоторые элементы через `@media` запросы.

Хотел узнать, правильно ли использовать `@media` запросы в связке с bootstrap?

Возможно ли делать полностью адаптивные сайты чисто на bootstrap без использования кастомных `@media`?

Или в связке с `@media` это нормально и не считается костылём?

Comment: Многое зависит от проекта, если не сложный, можно обойтись только `bootstrap`. В моей практике всегда были дополнительные `@media`. Это не проблема, сложнее находить такой способ расположения блоков, чтоб писать минимум стилей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от ТЗ. Если у вас макет от дизайнера, который не имеет представления о принципах бутсрапа, а от заказчика требование, чтобы верстка была строго pixel peffect, то тогда в некоторых случаях без дополнительно прописанных стилей не обойтись. А будут ли эти стили с использованием media? - Уже не особо важно. Главное, делайте код ваших стилей читаемым, пишите все медиа последовательно по размерам в одном месте.

Другое дело, когда есть возможность в бутсрапе делить на соответствующее количество колонок, показывать или прятать элементы, делать резиновыми фото и таблицы - всё это для разных экранов. Когда эти возможности верстальщик не использует, а лепит свои стили, вот это уже не верный подход. Ведь зачем тогда вообще грузить бутстрап, если его не использовать и нагружать страницу еще дополнительным кодом.

Подводя итог, кастомизация медиа зависит от конкретного случая и она вполне себе нормальное обычное явление, при условии, если этого же эффекта нельзя добиться готовыми решениями текущей библиотеки.